# How to install ssh in HP-UX B.11.11?

Tags: ssh, hp-ux

I'm looking for steps to install ssh over hp-ux 11.11.

Thanks,
Mandy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the hp instruction from [here](https://h20392.www2.hp.com/portal/swdepot/displayInstallInfo.do?productNumber=T1471AA)